# В окне поиска дубликатов на закрытие текст не переведён

Tags: дефект, локализация, закрытие-вопросов, дубликаты

**X results (top Y shown)**.

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ключ в трансе: `2e65f1bbce231476e732eb6e3ebc0e56`.

Интересно, что на английском только для случаев **many**. Если там до 4 результатов, то будет на русском.